# RecyclerView height

Tags: android

I have a layout as shown in the picture bellow. The recyclerView in the center is constrained by the toolbar layout at the top and the sumbox at the bottom. There is an 8dp margin on all constrain sides of the recycler view. I have a problem with setting the height of the recycler view. If I set the height to "match parent" the recyclerView renders bellow the toolbar and the buttons at the bottom. The same thing happens if I set it as "wrap conent" when the items in the view become numerous enough.If I set the height as a standard number like 600dp the problem is solved but if I run the layout on a screen that is slightly longer or shorter than the one I'm designing it on the same problem occurs. I want the recyclerView to expand verticaly to fill all the available space, but at the same time respect the vertical constrains. Is there a way to do this statically through XML or do I have to go into Kotlin and do this logically. I'm pretty sure I can do it if I do some calculations to find that height for that device, but this seems like a hacky way. 
[image]

Comment: @EvansChepsiror Thank you, that was the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using a `constraint layout` you can use `0dp` to set the `height` to `match_constraint`. It will automatically scale to fill the space after margins are calculated.